# How to get unix commands to work through standard windows command prompt

Tags: command-line

When I run cmd.exe, how do I get type unix commands such as 'ls', and 'pwd' to work? Is there a way I can get this to work without installing other software?

Comment: You might try Windows Powershell.
<br>
Here is a list of commands:
<br>
http://ss64.com/ps/

Answer (score 3):

I think it's impossible without installing additional software.

Anyway, if you accept to install additional software, this is exactly what you are looking for:

https://www.cygwin.com/

> Cygwin is:
>
> - A large collection of GNU and Open Source tools which provide    functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows.
> - A DLL (cygwin1.dll) which provides substantial POSIX API functionality.

Comment: I'm having the same question, and I've downloaded Cygwin, but I get the question about which category to install (Accessibility, Admin, Archive, ..., X11, Xfce). While checking those categories I've found things like `grep` (Base), `sed` (Base), but no `sort`, `awk`, `find`, .... Do you have any idea where I can find all those basic commands?

Comment: It seems to me that you need at least `bash`